# How to clear a redirect log file content in shell?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

I'm use redirect to logging `println` operation output to a `xxx.log` file. But I want move the log info to a separate file with name of current days date, such as `2017-08-18.log` by crontab.

I have attempt use `> xxx.log` shell command to clear the `xxx.log` file, but all content recovery when a new log generate.

How to clear the redirect log file?

**UPDATE**

1. After I'm execute `> xxx.log`, the `xxx.log` file's size is 0.But if my application print some new log, the `xxx.log` not only contains the new log info but also contains the former cleared log info.
2. After use `mv xxx.log xxx2.log`, new log info will write to `xxx2.log`.But if I use `rm xxx.log` instead of rename, the log action will stop. Besides, the process invoked by `nohup java -jar xxx.jar > xxx.log 2>&1 &` if you familiar with [playframework](https://www.playframework.com/), the execute file build by a `dist` command to generate the jar file.
3. `ps wx|grep "xxx.*.log` output:
   1)  `3912 pts/10   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto xxx.log`
   2)  `26234 pts/10   Sl     0:16 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java -Duser.dir=...something ignored... play.core.server.ProdServerStart` (it's the process execute command)

Hope it will be helpful, thanks again!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "but all content recovery when a new log generate".

Comment: @Kusalananda, It really confusing. After I'm execute `> xxx.log`, the `xxx.log` file's size is 0.But if my application print some new log, the `xxx.log` not only contains the new log info but also contains the former cleared log info.

Comment: it's sounds a thing that your application is keeping the logs is somewhere or buffer and it write back the logs, you can rename `xxx.log` once to check if it's recreating with same name or has rotation mechanism

Comment: @AFSHIN, After use `rm xxx.log xxx2.log`, new log info will write to `xxx2.log`.But if I use `rm xxx.log` instead of rename, the log action will stop. Besides, the process invoked by `nohup java -jar xxx.jar > xxx.log 2>&1 &`.

Comment: please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/386852/edit) in your question with these details + post the output of `ps wx|grep "xxx.*.log"

Comment: Hi, @AFSHIN, I have add message we just discussed, hope it will be clear.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your log file stays opened by the application that is writing to it. If you truncate the file (`> file.log`), your app will still write to it from the point of its last write (due to the truncation, I suppose your file will be filled with 0 bytes till that point). If you move the file, your app will continue to write to it since, once opened, its name doesn't matter. If you remove the file, the blocks won't be freed from the disk and the app will still be writing to them, even if the file is not visible any longer in your directory.

This is a classic scenario. Your application must:

- either reopen the log file periodically
- or detect that it has been truncated and reopen it
- or wait for a special signal that tells it "close your current log file and reopen it"

Else, there is nothing you can do externally except restarting your application. You would then do it the same way as `logrotate`:

- first move the log file under a new name
- optionally `touch` the log file with its old name so that the file exists
- restart the application to force it to stop writing to the old log file and to start writing to the new one.

Comment: Maybe I need some log tools in my application, such as log4j or write myself, restart the application for logging is not allowed.Thanks a lot

Comment: @LoranceChen Restart is an extreme case when you have no control over the application, which was my assumption. If the Java application is yours, then yes, of course, use a dedicated tool for your logs. log4j [apparently offers a mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1050318/7233423) for log rotation through RollingFileAppender

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with Perl you could run this little script:

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);

$fbase = "tmp-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M.log";

while(<>)
{
  $fnamenew = strftime $fbase, localtime;

  if ($fnamenew ne $fname)
  {
    print "logging to: $fnamenew\n";
    $fname = $fnamenew;
    close OUT;
    open OUT, ">$fname";
  }
  print OUT $_;
}
```

Use it like: `$mycomputation | perl script.pl`. It will append all input to a filename built from the given time pattern, here `tmp-YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MI.log`. On each new line of input, the pattern is rebuilt and checked against the old one. Should it differ then the input is piped to the new file and the old one is closed.

Comment: Hi, I'm not familiar with perl.The script has a error: `./perl.pl: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
` and another line `./perl.pl: line 1: use POSIX qw(strftime);'`.

Comment: For the record: This was related to using the wrong interpreter. The script needs to be run with `perl script.pl` or with `#!/usr/bin/perl` in line 1.